# Ubuntu 22.04 UFW NAT problems

Tags: networking, 22.04, firewall, ufw, nat

I've done an in-place upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and I've found that NAT no longer functions on this firewall box. Before the upgrade, the private network could reach the Internet just fine. I'm apparently missing something simple in re-setting this up.

Public <-- enp2s0 -- this box -- eno1 --> Private network

After flailing around for a while, I performed an

apt-get purge ufw && apt-get install ufw

ufw status verbose gives me:

```
Status: active

Logging: on (medium)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

/etc/defaults/ufw has:

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

/etc/ufw.conf has:

```
# /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
#

# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=yes

# Please use the 'ufw' command to set the loglevel. Eg: 'ufw logging medium'.
# See 'man ufw' for details.
LOGLEVEL=medium
```

/etc/ufw/before.rules has:

```
# rules.before
#
# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
#   ufw-before-input
#   ufw-before-output
#   ufw-before-forward
#
# nat Table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic from eth1 through eth0.
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.255.0/24 -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't be processed
COMMIT

# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
```

Two questions:

1. What am I forgetting to do to get NAT working?
2. It appears that sometimes ufw isn't starting on boot. The logs don't show any reason for this. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

After updating to Ubuntu 22.04 my NAT also was not working. On investigation I found that all NAT rules were still in place.

The problem was the OpenVPN Networking Configuration was not allowing routing. I did the following steps.

1. Edit the following file.

   sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
2. Add the following line. I just removed the comment character from my conf file.

   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
3. Run this to load the new setting.

   sudo sysctl -p
4. Above command will output

   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
5. From my side I disabled and enabled ufw also

   sudo ufw disable
   sudo ufw enable

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-22-04